# Violation of PRIMARY KEY. Cannot insert duplicate keys in many-with-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert table in many-with-many relationship:

```
DECLARE @TransactionTempTable Table
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, OperationName nvarchar(100)
, CurrentAccountID int
, AmountMoney decimal
, ExecutionDate datetime    
, RateValue money
)

INSERT INTO @TransactionTempTable 
(OperationName, CurrentAccountID, AmountMoney, ExecutionDate, RateValue)
SELECT [Operation Name] AS OperatioName         
, A.AccountID AS CurrentAccountID
, dbo.Amount([AmountMin],[AmountMax]) AS AmountMoney
, Dates.item AS ExecutionDate
, 0 AS RateValue              
FROM ExcelDatabase.dbo.Transactions T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateDate(GETDATE(),[Rate],[Period]) AS Dates
INNER JOIN Gurskiy_EconomicApp.DBO.Accounts A ON T.Account = A.AccountName

DECLARE @minID int = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @TransactionTempTable)
DECLARE @maxID int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @TransactionTempTable)
DECLARE @lastID int
DECLARE @SplitCategories Table (CategoryName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)

WHILE (@minID<=@maxID)
BEGIN
`INSERT INTO Gurskiy_EconomicApp.dbo.Transactions(CurrentAccountID,` `AmountMoney, ExecutionDate, RateValue)`


SELECT  
CurrentAccountID
            , AmountMoney
            , ExecutionDate
            , RateValue
        FROM @TransactionTempTable
        WHERE ID = @minID   
    SET @lastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO @SplitCategories
SELECT * 
FROM Gurskiy_EconomicApp.dbo.fnSplit( 
    (SELECT 
        OperationName 
    FROM @TransactionTempTable 
    WHERE ID = @minID)
, ',')

INSERT INTO Gurskiy_EconomicApp.dbo.TransactionCategory(TransactionID, CategoryID)
SELECT 
    @lastID
    , C.CategoryID
FROM @SplitCategories AS SC
INNER JOIN  Gurskiy_EconomicApp.dbo.Categories AS C ON SC.CategoryName = C.CategoryName

SET @minID = @minID+1
END
```

This is my code. I can't insert CategoryID and TransactionID in the table TransactionCategory, but table "Transactions" is filling correct and table Categories is also have filled.  I've got just a simple mistake about dublicates. But I can't find any mistake in my code. Help plz, this task eat my mind in the end of the day. 
Definition of TransactionCategory table:

```
CREATE TABLE TransactionCategory
(
    CategoryID int NOT NULL,
    TransactionID int NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT transaction_category_pk PRIMARY KEY (CategoryID, TransactionID), 

CONSTRAINT FK_Category 
  FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories (CategoryID), 

 CONSTRAINT FK_Transaction 
      FOREIGN KEY (TransactionID) REFERENCES Transactions (TransactionID)
)
```

Comment: So what's the definition (DDL) of the `TransactionCategory` table?

Comment: Added definition of TransactionCategory table.

Comment: http://www.tsqltidy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to insert `@lastID, C.CategoryID` into `TransactionCategory`. `@lastID` is generated by identity so I assume that it is different in each iteration. Am I right? However, `@lastID` is constant within a single iteration so `C.CategoryID` must be unique.  `C.CategoryID` comes from `Categories` table and I also assume that it is PK so there are no duplicated category identifiers in this table. Could you confirm?

It means that duplicates are caused by joining `@SplitCategories` with `Categories`. In other words it seems to me that `@SplitCategories` contains duplicates. To confirm, you can add the following line before insert and we will see:

```
select * from @SplitCategories
```

I think that the problem might be in `fnSplit` function. Maybe it splits `OperationName` in the wrong way. Could you show the source code of `fnSplit` and example data from the `OperationName` column?

Comment: I solved it. It was necessary to clear @SplitCategories table before add something